# Quickest way to call a computationally expensive function many times in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a function that is somewhat computationally expensive, we are talking about 2–5ms here.

```js
function heavyWork() {
  // ...
}
```

`heavyWork()` gets called a couple hundert times by different parts of my code at once which blocks Node.js' event loop. I was thinking about moving it to a child process by using [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), however even just sending ~500 IPC messages takes about the same time as computing it in the main process. Theoretically I could live with this solution, it's just a bit slower than before and does not block the event loop, though I would like to speed things up.

The other thing I tried was using [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads). However spawning that many threads was obviously even slower than the previous approach.

I will probably have to find a way to batch messages before sending them to the worker process unless there is a way of achieving this in Node that I have not tried yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a solution that I know of. I think creating batches is your best bet.

Some things I would consider:

- Is it possible to cache the result?
- Use setInterval to ensure that I don't wait for batches to fill up before dispatching.
- Create a partioner function that is responsible for evaluating how the work should be distributed. E.g. if the current batch is small then just run it on main thread. The partioner can look at the load of different cores and then distribute the load accordingly. Also if I only have 1 core and 2 threads then the batch size should be smaller than if I have 4 cores and 8 threads available.
- To help my partioner I could also create a wrapper around my heavyWork functions that denotes the expected workload on a scale from 1-5, where 5 is very CPU intensive work
- As a rule of thumb I would not spawn more worker threads than 2x the number of cores. This reduces the risk of swapping

[(My idea of a partioner function is borrowed from Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl)